# get object property without prompting undefined error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this object, it has redundant property, sometime id is present sometime id2 is present. I've no control over the source.

```
const obj = {
      id: 123, // one of this is gone depends on the condition
      id2: 123 // one of this is gone depends on the condition
    }
```

How can I assign the value to `getId` to either `id` or `id2` of `obj`?

Tried this but this will trigger undefined error and crashed my entire app.
`const getId = obj.id ? obj.id : obj.id2`

Comment: Do you want to assign `id` to `getId` variable ?

Comment: @Mr.Developer either id or id2

Comment: What you tried actually works fine, Can u show the error that you get?

Comment: Referencing `obj.id` when the `id` property is missing does NOT crash anything in node.js.  You would just have a value of `undefined`.  No crash.  You would only get a crash (actually an exception) when referencing `obj.id` if `obj` itself was `undefined`.  So, something is NOT correct in how you write your question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = { id2 : "some value" };
const getId = obj.id || obj.id2 || "both are absent";
console.log(getId);
```

```js
var obj = {};
const getId = obj.id || obj.id2 || "both are absent";
console.log(getId);
```

You can use `||` operator and get either of the values.

Comment: obj.id is undefined if id is not present in obj, this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @SharonChai yea if `id` is not present then it will automatically picks the value of `id2`.

Comment: no it will crash my entire app because id is not present in an object, you can try

Comment: @SharonChai no it wont.  I have updated my answer with the code snippet. You can see that.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `obj.id` exist and then assign the value to `getId`. Try following

```js
const obj = {
  id: 123, // one of this is gone depends on the condition
  id2: 123 // one of this is gone depends on the condition
}
const getId = (typeof obj.id != "undefined") ? obj.id : obj.id2;
console.log(getId);
```

**Edited**

After @SharonChai comment I am modifying my answer, so you add `!==` in ternary operator which is more better and faster.

```
const getId = (typeof obj.id !== "undefined") ? obj.id : obj.id;
```

Comment: why not `!==` ?

Comment: @SharonChai - `!==` is preferred, though it makes no difference in this specific case because `typeof` always returns a string and it is being compared to a string.

Comment: @SharonChai thanks for letting me know, I really appreciate +1

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

When both `id` & `id2` is present :

```js
var obj = {
      id: 123, // one of this is gone depends on the condition
      id2: 123 // one of this is gone depends on the condition
    }

var getId; 

Object.keys(obj).length ? getId = Object.keys(obj).map(item => obj[item]) : getId = "No property found in obj"; 

console.log(getId);
```

When any one of them (`id` or `id2`) is present :

```js
var obj = {
      id: 123
    }

var getId; 

Object.keys(obj).length ? getId = Object.keys(obj).map(item => obj[item]) : getId = "No property found in obj"; 

console.log(getId);
```

When none of them is present :

```js
var obj = {
    }

var getId; 

Object.keys(obj).length ? getId = Object.keys(obj).map(item => obj[item]) : getId = "No property found in obj"; 

console.log(getId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether the one property is not available and then use the other. You can do this in a multitude of ways:

```
function getId(obj) {
  return "id" in obj ? obj.id : obj.id2;
  return obj.hasOwnProperty("id") ? obj.id : obj.id2;
  return obj.id !== undefined ? obj.id : obj.id2;
}
```